# How to make a sprite point at the mouse. XNA C#

Tags: sprite, trigonometry

If you would look at this diagram [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trigonometry_triangle.svg), I need to find angle A by only knowing the length of all sides of a right triangle.

I don't know trig and need some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually 2 questions in your post.

How to make a sprite point at the mouse. XNA C#:

You will have to calculate the direction between the position of the sprite and the position of the mouse.
This can be done using trigonometry functions. In this case: Arctangens2

So let's use the math library:

```
MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
Math.Atan2((double)mouseState.Y - sprite.Y, (double)mouseState.X - sprite.X); //this will return the angle(in radians) from sprite to mouse.
```

In your trigonometry example you will see that those values actually are:

```
Math.Atan2(BC, AC);
```

or

```
Math.Atan2(Ydiff, Xdiff);
```

I hope this helps =D

Cheers,

TomHashNL

Answer (score 1):

I found my final solution to be:

```
Vector2 direction = targetPosition - currentPosition;
direction.Normalize();
float rotationInRadians = (float)Math.Atan2((double)direction.Y, 
                             (double)direction.X) + MathHelper.PiOver2;
```

rotationInRadians is a raw value that can be passed to the sprite batch for the correct rotation amount--no further code is needed. Also, you may notice incorrect results if you're rotating the sprite on a corner rather than the middle.